# Calling Java from command line - Linux vs Windows

Tags: java, linux, shell, command-line-interface, classpath

On Windows I run the following command and it work;

```
java -cp "./libs/*;" SampleJavaApp
```

When I try to run the same command on Linux (CentOS 6) I get

```
Error: Could not find or load main class SampleJavaApp
```

`SampleJavaApp` has no package

Any insight as to why would be appreciated.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The Java Version was the problem, as well as the :

Comment: Is there a CLASSPATH environment variable? (`echo $CLASSPATH`)

Comment: Are you sure that the class is compiled and you are running from the correct director?

Comment: @Skemelio echo $CLASSPATH returns nothing, should I have set something ? there

Comment: I will tell you what I did. I've set the CLASSPATH and I compile .java files using `javac -d $CLASSPATH /path/to/your/java_file/file.java`. With this all the compiled classes are stored in the directory that the CLASSPATH points to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of the classpath (`-cp` argument) uses the operating system path separator, to match the behavior of `PATH`. So you want `:` instead of `;` for separating paths.

Also, you seem to be using an empty path element when I think you want to explicitly reference the current directory `.`.

Also, I think the handling of the `*` wildcard varies by Java implementation, so you need to make sure the versions match.

Comment: the Java versions don't match I'm updating that, didnt understand what you meant by "Also, you seem to be using an empty path element when I think you want to explicitly reference the current directory .."

Comment: If you want the current directory to be on the classpath, make sure to reference `.` in the `-cp` argument. That said, a possibly *much* better solution would be to just compile all your classes with actual package declarations to match your directory structure.

Comment: “…the handling of the `*` wildcard varies by Java implementation…”  It doesn’t.  See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE__GUID-8CAE5D46-28F3-49B8-AAF5-EE79DC092E5D.

Comment: @VGR: That's true for newer versions of Java (version 9 and newer, IIRC?), but older JVMs definitely did not support wildcards like that. I remember needing to list every JAR on the classpath individually, which can lead to some *very* long classpaths.

Comment: True, but wildcards in classpaths [has been supported since Java 6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).